# How can get value with async method in angular?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, methods

i need to EventStateName in *ngFor, how can get value with async method, but was error.

**Display Screen**
[image: Display Screen]

**Error Screen**
[image: Error Screen]

i calling getEventStateById without async method after undefined value, i did a search about it, but frankly, I didn't understand much from the explanations. Can you help me to solve this problem.

```
export interface EventState { id?: number; name: string; }
```

```
export class DashboardComponent {
  events: Event[] = [];

  constructor(private eventService: EventService, private eventStateService: EventStateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEvents();
  }

  getEvents() {
    this.eventService.getAll().subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
          this.events = data;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  getEventStateById(id: number): EventState {
    let eventState: EventState;

    this.eventStateService.getById(id).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        if (data != null) {
          eventState = data
        }
      }
    });

    return eventState;
  }
}
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="events != null && events.length > 0">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of events">
        <td>
            #{{ item.id }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.title }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.location }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.eventDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' }}
            <i class="mdi mdi-circle-medium text-muted align-middle"></i>
            {{ item.eventDate | date: 'HH:mm' }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.insertedDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' }}
            <i class="mdi mdi-circle-medium text-muted align-middle"></i>
            {{ item.insertedDate | date: 'HH:mm' }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.updatedDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy' }}
            <i class="mdi mdi-circle-medium text-muted align-middle"></i>
            {{ item.updatedDate | date: 'HH:mm' }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.eventStateId }}
            <!-- {{ getEventStateById(item.eventStateId).name }} -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Each time the DOM gets updated, the `getEventStateById` gets called resulting in an endless spam of http calls. You could add the information needed for each item in the `getAll` BE function, or fetch them before rendering the table.